# C++ &-Operator Overload - Addressable R-Value Syntax-Cheat

Tags: c++

I stumbled upon something weird. We all know the taking the address of the return value from a function-call is not allowed - since it's an r-value.

But this seems to be fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int val;
    Foo* operator &() { // <-- just like normal "&"
        return this;
    }
};

Foo test() {
    return Foo{3};
} 

int main() {  
    Foo* p = &test(); // <-- wtf? allowed and works
    printf("%d", p->val);
}
```

Maybe by overloading the "&"-operator, the return value of first brought into scope of the caller (living on the stack, I guess) and therefore addressable.

Yields deterministic results on (Clang-14 and GCC-12)

Question is: **Undefined Behaviour or Legal?**

---

Assembler output clearly shows, that the return value is cached.

```
[Clang 14.0.0 without arguments]
main:                                   # @main
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    call    test()
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 16], eax <---
    lea     rdi, [rbp - 16]           <---
    call    Foo::operator&()
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
    mov     esi, dword ptr [rax]
    movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 16
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Extreme undefined behavior. Forecast: [major nasal demon storm](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), at least an 8.0 on the Richter scale.

Comment: This is 100% UB.  You are only not allows to use `&` on rvalue built in types.  There is nothing stopping you from doing this on class types as long you've overloaded it, which puts you in UB land.

Comment: The existence of the operator doesn't make it more or less "on the stack". You can call any member function on an rvalue (unless it's lvalue-ref qualified), and compilers must make it work, including spilling an object from a register so `this` makes sense inside the member. It doesn't change the object's value category either way, and a pointer is no less dangling on account of it.

Comment: Your `operator &()` is completely valid.  You correctly wrote that operator such that `(&test())->val` would work as expected.  `p->val` is dereferencing a dangling pointer however.

Comment: _"wtf? allowed and works"_ - Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and run it again. At least [gcc barks](https://godbolt.org/z/orbhdos5e)

Answer (score 10):

There's two separate questions here. First, will it compile? Second, will it work as intended?

The code in question compiles because

```
Foo* p = &test();
```

translates into

```
Foo* p = test().operator&();
```

which is perfectly legal. For example, compare against something like this:

```
std::string makeAString() {
    return "whee!";
}

auto length = makeAString().length(); // Perfectly fine
```

This code is legal, just as yours is.

However, there's a separate question about whether it will work correctly. And as mentioned in the comments, no it won't, because the pointer you're storing in `p` points to an object whose lifetime has ended. Using that pointer results in undefined behavior.

So, in that sense, your code will compile, but it's not a good idea to run it. :-)

Comment: so all in all. Pointers are the best way to shoot yourself in the head by "pointing" on your foot? i guess ... :-)

Comment: @StefTheDrummer well, not actually, return `*this` as reference still produce a dangling reference. (side note: this is actually useful in chaining methods)

Comment: also note the lifetime end at end of full expression (not when you return `this`)

Comment: The compiler is allowed to reject the program, since it is guaranteed UB on execution

Answer (score 8):

The behavior of your program is undefined.

User-defined operators have different semantics than the built-in operators.  User-defined operators behave just like the function calls they actually are.  Since your overloaded `operator&` is not ref-qualified, there's no reason it can't be called on an rvalue.

This doesn't change the lifetime of the object though.  There is no pointer-lifetime-extension.  `Foo* p = &test()` still yields a dangling pointer, since the lifetime of the temporary `Foo` object returned by `test` ends at the end of the full expression.  Attempting to dereference `p` beyond that point results in undefined behavior.  Remember, undefined behavior really means undefined.  Anything can happen, and "appears to work" is included in "anything".